# selection a file from QComboBox and open Qt C++

Tags: c++, file, qt

I have a window where I will open a file and I will put in the principal window. The problem is that the variables It is of the principal window and It is not of this window

```
        ui->nameEdit->setText(text);
        ui->textEdit->setText(name);
        ui->dateEdit->setDate(fecha);
```

error C2039: 'nameEdit' : is not a member of 'Ui::pacientes'

How could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your `QComboBox` is filled correct, you want to set the directory on that item. for example you have 3 files in the `QComboBox` file1.dat, file2.txt and file3.xml.

then i would connect the `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)` signal to the function and do something like ...

`QString pathToDirectory = "C://Users//Jaime//Desktop//interfaz//pacientes";
QString currentFileName = cmb.currentText(); <br>
QFile file( QString("%1//%2").arg(pathToDirectory, currentFileName) ); <br>
// do stuff with that file`

Comment: ok, I have a `qDebug<<name` later of `QDate` and it is showing `""` in the output. It is not taking the text.

Comment: sorry, I replaced my code with yours. Out the `if`, and down line it is qDebug. It is showing `""`.

Comment: what is the files structure/content?

it could be possible that you read the lines, but they are empty or does only contain one line or something

Comment: It is .txt, with text in three line. In other window I can write the .txt and save, in this window I read the files.

Comment: could it be possible that the `QFile` on the given path does not exist? check the path you generate (pathOfDirectory + currentFileName) to ensure that you have opened the correct file

Comment: pathOfDirectory take the route, but currentFileName hasn't nothing.

Comment: then replace `cmb.currentText()` with `cmb.itemText(index)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23757/discussion-between-jaime-spa-and-zaiborg)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
comb.currentText()
```

char limit

Comment: `QString files = p.filePath(comb.currentText());` with qDebug() it say me the value is "C:/Users/Jaime/Desktop/interfaz/pacientes". It is not getting the file.

Comment: Then you either haven't put anything in the combobox, or haven't selected an entry.  If either of those is true, the current index will return -1.